# How to establish dependency on 2 maven project on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have 2 projects, project A has the dao and pojo classes (to be used on several projects) and project B has the business rules, controllers and JSPs. I'm migrating them to a maven structure now.

How do I establish on project B that it depends on A? Before maven this dependency was defined on P at Properties > Deployment Assembly.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You add a Maven dependency?

Comment: Yes.  However you define project A (`groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`), put that same info into the `dependencies` section of the pom.xml for project B.

Comment: You need to learn the basic mechanics of Maven. Sonatype has [a selection of books](http://www.sonatype.com/resources/books), some of which are available for free as HTML or PDF.

Comment: Thanks, guys! It worked! I have been trying to learn how to use Maven for sometime now, but I always arrive at a point where things diverge and I find myself at a loss. I'll check those Bonatype books!